# Detox matchers work locally but fail on Circle CI

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, e2e-testing, circleci, detox

#### Description

As I'm working on a React Native Typescript project, I'm having trouble implementing e2e testing on my CI.

I am running Detox locally on a Mac with Catalina 10.15.6. The tests pass consistently (after I fixed flakiness noted [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Flakiness.md)).

When I push my changes, Circle CI runs automatically (on a Mac), building correctly. Then, the tests all fail due to issues with the matchers (which work correctly locally).

#### Reproduction

1. Run Detox Build & Test locally.
2. Initiate Circle CI, configured to do both the above.

#### Expected Behavior

If the tests pass locally and all the matchers work, the same will occur on a Circle CI machine.

#### Environment

- Detox: ^17.0.0
- React Native: 0.62.2
- Node: 12.18.0
- Device: iPhone 11 Pro (Simulator)
- macOS: Catalina 10.15.6
- Xcode: 11.5.0
- Jest: ^24.9.0
- Jest Circus: ^26.1.0
- Typescript: ^3.8.3
- Yarn: 1.22.4

#### Logs

Here is the output from my failed test on Circle CI:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ /Users/distiller/project/node_modules/.bin/detox test --cleanup
detox[12206] INFO:  [test.js] cleanup=true reportSpecs=true useCustomLogger=true forceAdbInstall=false DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1599242684729 node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
detox[12207] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:49498...
detox[12207] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] xx.xxx.xxxxx launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 03E73092-B137-4FA2-B3F9-EE1901FCCC1E log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == "xxxx"'
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite is assigned to 03E73092-B137-4FA2-B3F9-EE1901FCCC1E {"type":"iPhone 11 Pro"}
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter an invalid email and error message should appear
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter an invalid email and error message should appear [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a registered email and pass the email input screen to login code entry
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a registered email and pass the email input screen to login code entry [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a valid email and invalid login code then error message should appear
detox[12207] INFO:  at e2e/firstTest.e2e.js:176:19 
 DO NOT REMOVE
detox[12207] INFO:  at e2e/firstTest.e2e.js:123:19 
 Something went wrong:  Error: Test Failed: Timed out while waiting for expectation: TOBEVISIBLE WITH MATCHER(identifier: == “xxxx”) TIMEOUT(1s)
TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a valid email and invalid login code then error message should appear [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a valid email then a valid login code and end up at the testing site preferences screen
detox[12207] INFO:  at e2e/firstTest.e2e.js:200:19 
 DO NOT REMOVE
detox[12207] INFO:  at e2e/firstTest.e2e.js:123:19 
 Something went wrong:  Error: Test Failed: Timed out while waiting for expectation: TOBEVISIBLE WITH MATCHER(identifier: == “xxxx”) TIMEOUT(1s)
TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should enter a valid email then a valid login code and end up at the testing site preferences screen [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should attempt to advance past testing site preferences screen without entering preference
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should attempt to advance past testing site preferences screen without entering preference [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should rank a testing site and advance to the availability page
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should rank a testing site and advance to the availability page [FAIL]
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should toggle a time slot, collapse an accordion, and then click submit
detox[12207] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] xxx.xxxx.xxxx launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 03E73092-B137-4FA2-B3F9-EE1901FCCC1E log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == "XXXXX"'
detox[12207] INFO:  Project Test Suite: should toggle a time slot, collapse an accordion, and then click submit [FAIL]

 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.e2e.js (174.609s)
  Project Test Suite
    ✕ should enter an invalid email and error message should appear (8205ms)
    ✕ should enter a registered email and pass the email input screen to login code entry (8695ms)
    ✕ should enter a valid email and invalid login code then error message should appear (10658ms)
    ✕ should enter a valid email then a valid login code and end up at the testing site preferences screen (13953ms)
    ✕ should attempt to advance past testing site preferences screen without entering preference (4959ms)
    ✕ should rank a testing site and advance to the availability page (5033ms)
    ✕ should toggle a time slot, collapse an accordion, and then click submit (9286ms)

  ● Project Test Suite › should enter an invalid email and error message should appear

    Test Failed: Failed expectation: TOBEVISIBLE WITH MATCHER(identifier: == “xxx”), View “<RCTUITextField: 0x7f9fb28ef600>” is not visible at point “{"x":59.333333333333343,"y":23.333333333333371}”; Window “<RCTRedBoxWindow: 0x7f9fb24b4650>” is above the tested view's window and its transparency around point “{"x":98.000001271565765,"y":309.66666730244958}” is below the tested threshold (0.5)
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.



  ● Project Test Suite › should enter a registered email and pass the email input screen to login code entry

    Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(identifier: == “xxx”)”
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.




  ● Project Test Suite › should enter a valid email and invalid login code then error message should appear

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'XXXXX' of undefined

      80 |   it("should enter a valid email and invalid login code then error message should appear", async () => {
      81 |     const {
    > 82 |       constant,
         |       ^
      83 |       constant2,
      84 |     } = await someFunction();
      85 |     await expect(constant).toBeVisible();

      at _callee4$ (firstTest.e2e.js:82:7)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
      at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:13

  ● Project Test Suite › should enter a valid email then a valid login code and end up at the testing site preferences screen

    Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(text == “xxxx”)”
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.



  ● Project Test Suite › should attempt to advance past testing site preferences screen without entering preference

    Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(text == “xxxx”)”
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.



  ● Project Test Suite › should rank a testing site and advance to the availability page

    Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(text == “xxxx”)”
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.



  ● Project Test Suite › should toggle a time slot, collapse an accordion, and then click submit

    Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(identifier: == “xxxx”)”
    TIP: To print view hierarchy on failed actions/matches, use loglevel verbose and above.



detox[12206] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you disable synchronization? This can introduce many issues.

Comment: I haven't yet tried that - I'll add it to my list to try tomorrow and let you know if it works. Thanks @LeoNatan!

Comment: @LeoNatan where would I include this bit of code to disable synchronization: ```await device.disableSynchronization();```. I'm unsure whether to put it in ```e2e/init.js``` or ```e2e/firstTest.e2e.js```. Or is there some third location?

Comment: @LeoNatan I tried adding ```await device.disableSynchronization``` to beforeEach like so in ```e2e/init.js```: ```beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
  await device.disableSynchronization();
});```. Unfortunately, even given this change, I had the same errors shown above.

Comment: Update: I have also tried putting the disable synchronization in beforeAll of the init.js and that failed as well.

Comment: I meant you shouldn’t disable sync.

Comment: Oh haha I see. No previously it was not disabled and was still failing @LeoNatan.